# How do I create a sub-menu with Bulma?

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, submenu, bulma

We've created a nav bar with dropdown menus, using Bulma, but some of the menu items need to have pop-out submenus (that would appear to the side).  Does Bulma have this capability?  I wasn't able to find any information about it in the Bulma docs -- if it doesn't, what would be the easiest way to go about this?  I need to keep the existing Bulma nav bar and menus as is (I'm extending the work of another developer on the team). Thanks very much for any clues!

Comment: You should reword your question, to remove the "open to other packages". Asking for software recommendations is strictly off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose I meant in addition to Bulma -- that is, I'm working with the menu system that another developer in the team just wrote and he's asked me to add a submenu....

Comment: For software recommendations, check out: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but be sure to read the help center, as they're usually a bit more strict on recommendations.